# Finding where a solution of a PDE is unique

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've solved the PDE $yu_x+xu_y=0$, with the condition $u(0,y)=e^{-y^2}$, and found that the solution is $u(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2}$, so the book ask where this solution is uniquely determined, the ansewer it gives is for $x^2\le y^2$, but I can't understand why.

Thanks in advance.